# JMeter JDBC Pool configuration

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter, database-connection, connection-pooling

Is there a practical use of JMeter's [JDBC Pool configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

I tried to use Max Number of Connections 10 and it caused issues with Oracle max connection reached.

It seems from documentation below that its usage is discourage, so I still wonder if there's scenarios that it could be useful.

> Max Number of Connections Maximum number of connections allowed in the
>   pool. In most cases, set this to zero (0). This means that each thread
>   will get its own pool with a single connection in it, i.e. the
>   connections are not shared between threads.  If you really want to use
>   shared pooling (why?), then set the max count to the same as the
>   number of threads to ensure threads don't wait on each other.

- Note In code I see it uses for connection pool `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical use is that you should start with [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) which will be **a replica** of your production JDBC pool configuration in order to have realistic load pattern(s).

If you detect a database performance problem you could play with pool settings (connections number, transaction isolation, etc) to determine the most performing configuration, once you have the evidence that these or that pool settings provide better performance you can report it to developers or devops and amend your application database connectivity settings according to your findings. Check out [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter) for JMeter connection pool settings explained.

From Oracle perspective I believe [Connection Pooling and Caching](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm) and [High-Performance Oracle JDBC Programming](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-oracle-jdbc-090470.html) will help a lot.

Comment: But if I use same pool in production and locally as hikaricp I don't gain anything by using it, am I correct?