# Error preloading the connection pool while running sql statement in Jmeter

Tags: mysql, jmeter

Error preloading the connection pool while running sql statement in Jmeter.

I am using below env:

- jdk1.8.0_151
- apache-tomcat-7
- commons-dbcp.jar (version: 2.1.1)
- commons-pool2-2.4.2
- apache-jmeter-3.1
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin

pfa jdbc connection,jdbc_request,request,response_data,sampler_result screenshots

[image: jdbc connection]

[image: jdbc_request]

[image: sampler request tab]

[image: sampler response tab]

[image: sampler result]

Comment: JMeter already have a built in connection pooling with dbcp. what are you trying to do and what is your exception?

Comment: @user7294900  I am tring to establish the mysql connection jmeter 3.1 and fetch some thing from the database and got this error "Error preloading the connection pool while running sql statement" for the statement :-- [Select Statement] Select top 1 CSTMRId from T_CSTMR ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: @user7294900 ,please check now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396569/jmeter-jdbc-pool-configuration) when even 10 max connection settings in oracle caused errors. I suggest you use `0` value in JDBC's Maximum number of connections as recommended in JMeter JDBC manual:

> Maximum number of connections allowed in the pool. In most cases, set this to zero (0).This means that each thread will get its own pool with a single connection in it, i.e. the connections are not shared between threads.